# Subset of levels sorting in pandas MultiIndex Series troubles

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, multi-index

I have a Series with 3-level MultiIndex:

```
print(ser_test):
                            Value
Date       Group Country         
2014-01-31 3     AE       example
                 AR       example
2014-02-28 3     AE       example
                 AR       example
2014-03-31 3     AE       example
                 AR       example
2014-04-30 3     AE       example
                 AR       example
2014-05-30 3     AR       example
2014-06-30 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-07-31 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-08-29 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-09-30 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-10-31 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-11-28 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
2014-12-31 2     AE       example
           3     AR       example
```

My goal is to sort Series firstly by **Country** and then by **Date**, ignoring **Group** level to achieve the next result:

```
                            Value
Date       Group Country         
2014-01-31 3     AE       example
2014-02-28 3     AE       example
2014-03-31 3     AE       example
2014-04-30 3     AE       example
2014-06-30 2     AE       example
2014-07-31 2     AE       example
2014-08-29 2     AE       example
2014-09-30 2     AE       example
2014-10-31 2     AE       example
2014-11-28 2     AE       example
2014-12-31 2     AE       example
2014-01-31 3     AR       example
2014-02-28 3     AR       example
2014-03-31 3     AR       example
2014-04-30 3     AR       example
2014-05-30 3     AR       example
2014-06-30 3     AR       example
2014-07-31 3     AR       example
2014-08-29 3     AR       example
2014-09-30 3     AR       example
2014-10-31 3     AR       example
2014-11-28 3     AR       example
2014-12-31 3     AR       example
```

And I need **Group** level further, so I can't simply eliminate it.

So I tried to use sort_index method like this:

```
print(ser_test.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date']))
```

or like that:

```
print(ser_test.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date'], sort_remaining = False))
```

In both cases I received a result, where **Group** level is involved in sorting process and have a priority before **Date** level:

```
                            Value
Date       Group Country         
2014-06-30 2     AE       example
2014-07-31 2     AE       example
2014-08-29 2     AE       example
2014-09-30 2     AE       example
2014-10-31 2     AE       example
2014-11-28 2     AE       example
2014-12-31 2     AE       example
2014-01-31 3     AE       example
2014-02-28 3     AE       example
2014-03-31 3     AE       example
2014-04-30 3     AE       example
2014-01-31 3     AR       example
2014-02-28 3     AR       example
2014-03-31 3     AR       example
2014-04-30 3     AR       example
2014-05-30 3     AR       example
2014-06-30 3     AR       example
2014-07-31 3     AR       example
2014-08-29 3     AR       example
2014-09-30 3     AR       example
2014-10-31 3     AR       example
2014-11-28 3     AR       example
2014-12-31 3     AR       example
```

I tried to use all the options of sort_index and achieved an unexpected success with this piece of code:

```
print(ser_test.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date'], ascending = [True, True]))

                            Value
Date       Group Country         
2014-01-31 3     AE       example
2014-02-28 3     AE       example
2014-03-31 3     AE       example
2014-04-30 3     AE       example
2014-06-30 2     AE       example
2014-07-31 2     AE       example
2014-08-29 2     AE       example
2014-09-30 2     AE       example
2014-10-31 2     AE       example
2014-11-28 2     AE       example
2014-12-31 2     AE       example
2014-01-31 3     AR       example
2014-02-28 3     AR       example
2014-03-31 3     AR       example
2014-04-30 3     AR       example
2014-05-30 3     AR       example
2014-06-30 3     AR       example
2014-07-31 3     AR       example
2014-08-29 3     AR       example
2014-09-30 3     AR       example
2014-10-31 3     AR       example
2014-11-28 3     AR       example
2014-12-31 3     AR       example
```

It's quite strange and I'm not sure that this is a universal way to get a guaranteed expected sorting result while **using a MultiIndex** is a critical option for me.

So, can you help me to understand sort_index principles and share to me a piece of code for this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try upgrade to last version of pandas, tested in pandas 0.25.0 and working nice:

```
print(df.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date']))
                            Value
Date       Group Country         
2014-01-31 3     AE       example
2014-02-28 3     AE       example
2014-03-31 3     AE       example
2014-04-30 3     AE       example
2014-06-30 2     AE       example
2014-07-31 2     AE       example
2014-08-29 2     AE       example
2014-09-30 2     AE       example
2014-10-31 2     AE       example
2014-11-28 2     AE       example
2014-12-31 2     AE       example
2014-01-31 3     AR       example
2014-02-28 3     AR       example
2014-03-31 3     AR       example
2014-04-30 3     AR       example
2014-05-30 3     AR       example
2014-06-30 3     AR       example
2014-07-31 3     AR       example
2014-08-29 3     AR       example
2014-09-30 3     AR       example
2014-10-31 3     AR       example
2014-11-28 3     AR       example
2014-12-31 3     AR       example
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jezrael !
I've updated pandas from 0.24.2 to 0.25.1 and sort_index is now working according to my expectations!